# Correct usage of atomics

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I've written a small lightweight push/pop queue based on a vector (figured it should be fast) like this:

```
template <typename T> class MyVectorQueue{

public:

    MyVectorQueue (size_t sz):my_queue(sz),start(0),end(0){}

    void push(const T& val){
       size_t idx=atomic_fetch_add(&end,1UL);
       if (idx==my_queue.size())
          throw std::runtime_error("Limit reached, initialize to larger vector");
       my_queue[idx]=val;
    }

    const T& pop(){
        if (start==end) 
           return end__;
        return my_queue[start.fetch_add(1UL)];
    }

    size_t empty()
    {
        return end==start;
    }

    const T& end() {
        return end__;
    }

private:
    T end__;
    std::atomic<size_t> start,end;
    std::vector<T> my_queue;    
};
```

The size of the vector should be known and 
I am wondering why is it not thread safe? In what circumstances does this mess my structure?

Comment: The code you have written is fine.  The more interesting part is what you do when the vector is filled up.

Comment: CODE IS BROKEN and there is no simple way to do it right. As the book said[1], lock free programming should be left to the experts, not me.   [1] The c++ Programming Language 4th ed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `start` and `end` are atomic variables, but using `std::vector::operator[]` is not atomic operation, making it not thread-safe.

---

Suppose you have 10 threads and the size of the `vector` is 5. Now, suppose all of them are executing, say `push`.

Now suppose all 10 threads may have passed the check and the `if (end==my_queue.size())` is evaluated to `false`, as and `end` has not reached the limit, meaning - the `vector` is not full.

Then, it's possible that all of them increment `end` and at the same time call `std::vector::operator[]`. At least 5 of the threads will try to access elements, "outside" the vector.

Comment: Since the indexes with which operator[] are called are unique per all threads, why should it matter?

Comment: Well, they are not that unique. Are these the only operations over the vector? I guess not. Somewhere something reads these values, right? Also, resizing the vector may cause reallocations of the internal memory of the vector, while some thread is reading from it. And many other things. Depends on the usage.

Comment: What do you mean not that unique? I'm strictly referring to these two functions and the size of the vector is set in the constructor. Helgrind bugs me in the push function.

Comment: @LucianMLI - see my edit (good question, by the way; you have +1 from me).

Comment: I see.. so how about if i get size_t idx=atomic_fetch_add(&end,1UL) and check this one to modify the vector?

Comment: @LucianMLI - can you clarify a bit more? I didn't get your idea.

Comment: @LucianMLI - you shouldn't edit your questions like this, as your question now is completely different with the first and makes my answer (almost) wrong/unhelpful. Anyway. `push` now looks better, but the same problem exists in `pop` now. After all, practically seems safe, but on theory, I'm almost sure, the standard forbids this, as still it will be possible for several threads to execute `operator[]` over the same vector at the same time, no matter if it's on different locations (and not causing reallocations)

Comment: @LucianMLI - actually, I may be wrong about the last thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951361/can-multiple-threads-access-a-vector-at-different-places . But I still think it's disallowed by the standard.

Comment: About the editing, I didn't know how to explain my idea right, sorry. And if  I do the same for the pop() will this be OK? And why would the standard forbid it? The size is fixed, the only problem would be index collision... wouldn't it?

Comment: @LucianMLI - not sure, see my last comment and the link in it. Maybe, it will be safe. I'll try to find some quote in the standard later.

Comment: I read it but I don't understand how and why cache invalidation would occur. I based my performance gain on fitting the vector (..of pointers) in the cache. Can't find a helpful article on the web, if you have a link it would be very helpful.

Comment: @LucianMLI - unfortunately, I don't. And I didn't find anything relevant (anything about threads on containers). I'd be happy if you find anything and you share it with me.

Comment: `std::vector`'s `operator[]` cannot contribute to a data race. Per C++11 23.2.2 [container.requirements.dataraces]/1 "For purposes of avoiding data races (17.6.5.9), implementations shall consider the following functions to be
const: `begin`, `end`, `rbegin`, `rend`, `front`, `back`, `data`, `find`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, `equal_range`, `at` and, except in associative or unordered associative containers, `operator[]`." These are all functions that do not modify the container, but are non-const so as to return modifiable references/iterators to the container contents.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `operator[]`  to push items, but this won't grow the vector in order to add the item. Therefore you'll get undefined behaviour (and probably an access violation) when trying to add an item to a index that does not exist.

Also, although you're using atomic operation on `start` and `end` the `vector` isn't atomic. So, for example, you could have multiple threads call `push`, they atomically alter `end` and then all call `operator[]` which isn't thread safe. Instead you should think about using a mutex and a [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) :

```
std::mutex mutex;
std::deque<T> my_queue;

void push(const T& val){
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
   //..code to check if full 
   my_queue.push_back(val);
}

const T& pop(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
    //code to check if empty and that start index does not pass end index
    T item=my_queue.front();
    my_queue.pop_front();
    return item;
}
```

Comment: The `lock_guard` in `push` and `pop` should be before the `//..code to check if full/empty` code.

Answer (score 1):

Although this code *looks dangerously wrong* on many accounts at first glance, it actually only contains a single problem. Otherwise it is perfectly fine, within its limitations.

You are creating a `vector` initialized to some particular size, and you do not allow more elements being pushed than this given size. That is somewhat "odd behavior" but if this is what is desired, then there is no problem.

Calling `vector::operator[]` looks very troublesome for thread-safety because it is not an atomic operation, but it is really not a problem as such. All that `vector::operator[]` does is return a reference to the element corresponding to the index that you provide. It doesn't do any bounds-checking or reallocation or any other complicated stuff that *might* break in presence of concurrency (in all likelihood, it boils down to something like a single LEA instruction).
You are using `fetch_add` in every case, which is the right mindset to guarantee that indices are unique among threads. If indices ar unique, no two threads will ever access the same element, insofar it does not matter whether that access is atomic. Even if several threads atomically increment a counter at the same time, they will all get different results (i.e. no increments are "lost" on the way). At least that's the *theory*, and it's true for as far `push` is concerned, too.

The one **real** problem lies in the `pop` function where (other than in `push`) you do not atomically `fetch_add` the index (or more correctly, *both* indices) into local variables prior to comparing them and to calling `operator[]`.
This is a problem since `if(start==end)` is not atomic as such, and it is not atomic in conjuction with calling `operator[]` a few lines later. You must fetch *both* values to be compared in one atomic operation, or you have no way of asserting that the comparison is meaningful in any way. Otherwise:

- Another thread (or another two or three threads) can increment either `start` or `end` (or both) while you compare them, and your check for having reached the maximum capacity will fail.
- Another thread may increment `start` after that check, but before the `fetch_add` inside the call to `operator[]` is seen, causing you to index out-of-bounds and invoking undefined behavior.

The non-intuitive thing to note here is that **although** you do "the right thing" by using atomic operations, the program will still not behave correctly, since not just *individual* operations need to be atomic.

Comment: The OP edited the question "a bit", which was significant change. `push` was with the same issue as `pop`. OP edited the implementation during our conversation in the comments below my answer. But I my observations were exactly the same. +1 from me.

Comment: @KirilKirov: Ah OK, I had not noticed that there had been an edit, only saw the current version. Will have a look at the previous one too  :-)

Comment: @KirilKirov: You're right, the original code has a very similar issue in `push` as well, and problem exactly as you describe in your answer.

Comment: Thanks. The edit is very misleading, I asked the OP not to do such edits in the future, because it really changes the whole question and makes some answers wrong/unhelpful/etc.

Comment: Even if you `fetch_add`ed the indices into local variables correctly, that wouldn't actually resolve the problem. Imagine we have one item in the queue. Assume we want to pop it and correctly get both start and end and increment start while doing so (all atomically), but before we can read the item, another thread starts pushing a new element on the now empty thread. We have one thread reading and another writing to the same memory location without any synchronization -> undefined behavior

Comment: Basically: Data structures are non trivial to implement correctly in all cases. Concurrent data structures are *much* harder to get right and  lock-free concurrent data structures are orders of magnitudes harder than those. Best to stay away from self-rolled solutions if you want something that has even a chance to work correctly.